# Time Machine target disk over WiFi?

Tags: wifi, time-machine, mac-mini

I have a Macbook and I need an incremental backup solution over WiFi. Time Capsule or AirPort Extreme with attached HDD is perfect fit. But I want to find cheaper solution if exist.

How about Mac mini? I thought about Mac mini with only internal disk but has separated backup partition. Can I get Time Machine backup over WiFi with only Mac mini?
If you have used this, please let me know whether it is possible and how it is reliable.

Or any other recommendable solution is exist, please let me know.

Direct attachment of some external HDD to Macbook is not an option, because I think I will forget attaching it very easily, so it won't effective to me. Backup disk should be connected to my Macbook automatically when I connected my home WiFi network.

Comment: You can try a Google search to be more specific with your hardware. From suggest I 've got a french tutorial for Synology :
http://www.synology.com/support/tutorials_show.php?q_id=481
and an other in English
http://www.synology.com/us/solutions/backup/time_machine/time_machine.php
Try in your language !

I maked a test with my internet box (tv - adsl - modem - hdd), it was really slow to be nice (never try with a time Capsule).

Comment: A TC is cheaper than a Mac mini so I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @patrix I think I can get a used Mac mini with cheap price. It's very hard to find used TC or AirportExtreme in here. (not U.S.) And mainly, I'm looking for some new trial and possibility.